# Calculate quintiles/deciles from an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given the following array:

```
[13, 468, 3, 6, 220, 762, 97, 16, 522, 69, 119, 2895, 1255, 49, 19, 261, 9, 140, 55, 20, 6, 22, 6, 17, 115]
```

I need to calculate the value that is at the 20th, 40th, 60th, and 80th percentile. The steps would be to order the array from low to high, count the total number of values, determine what value is at the 20th percentile, etc. (for example, if there are 10 numbers in order from low to high, the 2nd value would be the 20th percentile).

This is stored in a variable and I know I can sort the numbers like this:
`ticks6.sort();`

and get the number of values in the array with this:

`var newticks=ticks6.length;`

I have no idea how to do the next part though where I figure out the percentiles, but looking for a solution in jquery or javascript.

Comment: Please attempt something, and post what you have tried. SO is not here to do your work for you, but to help figure out why something is not giving an expected output

Comment: @depperm I added how far I was able to get, which is the first to steps of sorting and counting the number of values. The next part is where I'm stuck.

Comment: _looking for a solution in jquery..._ What does **jquery** here? jquery is only useful for working with **DOM**. Arrays can be easily handled by pure Javascript, without jquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use like this:

```
var arr = [13, 468, 3, 6, 220, 762, 97, 16, 522, 69, 119, 2895, 1255, 49, 19, 261, 9, 140, 55, 20, 6, 22, 6, 17, 115];
arr.sort();
var len =  arr.length;
var per20 =  Math.floor(len*.2) - 1;

console.log(arr[per20]);
```

//similarly

```
var per40 =  Math.floor(len*.4) - 1;
console.log(arr[per40]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to add a 0 before the .2 to get this to work. `len[per20]` comes back as undefined. `per20` does come back with a value though. What is the `len` supposed to add?

Comment: Sorry its a typo ..it should be arr[per20]..I have edited.

Comment: Thanks. This is working, but with one major problem. When I sort my array it comes back like this: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 104, 108, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 111, 115, 115]` It's sorting alphabetically instead of numerically

Comment: Nevermind...got it: `arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})`

Answer (score 3):

The [Simple Statistics](http://simplestatistics.org/) library has a [quantile](http://simplestatistics.org/docs/#quantile) function you can use for this:

```
ss.quantile([13, 468, 3, 6, 220, 762, 97, 16, 522, 69, 119, 2895, 1255, 49, 19, 261, 9, 140, 55, 20, 6, 22, 6, 17, 115], 0.2)
=> 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
tricks6.sort();
var length = tricks6.length;

var twentieth = sorted[math.floor((length-1)*.2)] //do for all
```

Comment: `tricks6.sort();` is not sorting the array `var scores = [1, 2, 10, 21];
scores.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]`

Answer (score 0):

You can easely sort your array :

```js
console.log([13, 468, 3, 6, 220, 762, 97, 16, 522, 69, 119, 2895, 1255, 49, 19, 261, 9, 140, 55, 20, 6, 22, 6, 17, 115].sort(function(a,b){return a-b}))
```

Get the length of the array : `myArray.length`.
And the 20th percile `parseInt(myArray.length * 0.2)` => 2